# Recursive setTimeout in eventListener function (drum sequencer)

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, settimeout

I'm trying to fire a drum sequence on the click of a button using an event listener. Inside the event listener I iterate through the drum pattern using forEach and delay the playback of each (selected) iteration using setTimeout. The sequencer runs through one time and then stops. What I can't seem to figure out is how to structure the code block so that it continues to loop until the user clicks stop.

Here is what I have so far.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        cells.forEach((cell, i) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (cell.classList.contains('selected')) {
                    cell.childNodes[1].play();
                }
            }, i * 500);
        });
});
```

I've tried using a recursive function that was mentioned in another post by wrapping the forEach method inside another function and then recalling that function before the event listener function closes. I've also tried firing two separate setTimeout functions, the second of which recalls the function that is wrapped around the forEach method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this might not be exactly what you are after, but I would strongly recommend moving this code into an ES6 class.

The main issue with what you have at the moment is that you don't know how many times the cells array is going to be looped over when the click event is fired. Your code essentially sets all of the timeouts at the start (think about setting 4 separate timers, one starting from 500 another from 1000, 1500, 2000). If you wanted this looping to be able to occur indefinitely, you would need an indefinite amount, or perhaps an individual timer for each beat that resets when it reaches the end.

Instead, I think a better solution is to store a variable that indicates the current position in the sequencer and sets a timeout that increments this variable after x amount of time, and resets back to the start once it reaches the end. This way you have only one timer that is counting down the time till the next beat. Once it reaches 0 it plays the next note and restarts.

```
class Sequencer {
    // playButton = btn;
    cells = [1,2,3,4]; // you would want to set this to your cells array
    currentBeatIndex = 0;
    isPlaying = false;

    constructor(msPerBeat) {
        this.msPerBeat = msPerBeat;
        // this.playButton.addEventListener('click', () => this.toggleStartStop())
    }
    
    toggleStartStop() {
        if (this.isPlaying) {
            this.stop();
        } else {
            this.start();
        }
    }

    stop() {
        this.isPlaying = false;
        // Could also set this.currentBeatIndex = 0 here if you wanted to return to the first beat when stopped.        
    }

    start() {
        this.isPlaying = true;
        this.playCurrentNoteAndSetTimeout();
    }

    playCurrentNoteAndSetTimeout() {
        if (this.isPlaying) {
            console.log(this.cells[this.currentBeatIndex]); // use your .play() method here
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.toNextBeat();
                this.playCurrentNoteAndSetTimeout(); // this is where your reccursion happens.
            }, this.msPerBeat)
        }
    }

    toNextBeat() {
        this.currentBeatIndex = ++this.currentBeatIndex % this.cells.length; // mod operator here allows us to loop back to beginning of array when we reach the end.
    }
    
}

const sequencer = new Sequencer(500) // 120 bpm
```

Try pasting this into your console and running sequencer.start() and then sequencer.stop()

As a sidenote, I'd recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&vl=en) about the event loop. I found it really helpful with understanding timeouts.

Comment: This is a very detailed and lengthy response! thank you very much. Admittedly, I'm still pretty new to programming (only started with my first console command a less than 6 months ago) so what you wrote here is a bit above my skill level. But it seems to make sense the more times I read it. Question, though: the first comment you have ("playButton = btn") would that be where I would place my querySelector reference to the html button tag? The button that I would click to initiate the sequence?

Comment: Yeah that's right! Sequencer is a very cool project to learn more about JS. Good luck, I'm sure you'll pick up a lot of new information on the way :)

Comment: Thank you! I've gotten most of it to work properly, but I've run into a different issue now. I want to add a conditional statement in playCurrentNoteAndSetTimeout() so that only the selected drum cells are played and the others are skipped over. In my original code I had it set so that if the cell had a CSS class of 'selected' then it would play, but I can't seem to get it to work properly here. So right now, even though I have nothing selected, on start() every cell will play at its set BPM. Not sure if this is relevant at all, but I did convert the drum cells from nodelist to a proper array.

Answer (score 0):

I think `setInterval` and `clearInterval` will probably do what you need.

Here I have a `play` method on my cells which simply pulses the circle over 500 ms, and I do something similar to your loop in `runPattern`.  I call this function once to start, and then call `setInterval(runPattern, /*time*/)`.  Storing the result of that value in the variable `interval`, I can then later stop the interval by calling `clearInterval(interval)`.

Note that `stop` does not stop the current sequence, only preventing the next one from beginning.  While we could change that, it's much more invasive to the existing code.

```js
const handler = (() => {
  const [red, blue, green, yellow] = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4'].map(
    (id, _, __, node = document.getElementById(id)) => ({
      play: () => {
        node.classList.add('pulse')
        setTimeout(() => node.classList.remove('pulse'), 500)
      }
    })
  )

  const cells = [red, green, red, blue, yellow, blue]

  const runPattern = () => {
    cells.forEach((cell, i) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            cell.play()
        }, i * 500);
    });
  }

  let running = false;
  let interval= null

  return {
    start: () => {
      if (!running) {
          running = true
          runPattern()
          interval= setInterval(runPattern, 500 * cells.length + 1000)
      }
    }, 
    stop: () => {
      running = false
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }
})()

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', handler.start)
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', handler.stop)
```

```css
#balls {position: relative}
span {margin: 50px; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 40px; height: 40px; border-radius: 50%; cursor: pointer; border: 1px solid #999}
.pulse {animation: pulse .5s;}
#b1 {background: #f00; left: 20px;}
#b2 {background: #00f; left: 90px;}
#b3 {background: #0f0; left: 160px}
#b4 {background: #ff0; left: 230px}
@keyframes pulse {
  0%   {width: 40px; height: 40px; margin: 50 50 50}
  50%   {width: 60px; height: 60px; margin: 30 40 60}
  100% {width: 40px; height 60px; margin: 50 50 50}
}
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<div id ="balls">
  <span id="b1"></span>
  <span id="b2"></span>
  <span id="b3"></span>
  <span id="b4"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Very detailed. Although, like I said in a previous comment, I'm still pretty new to programming and this is a bit above from what I'm familiar with. Are you able to explain the first block (the handler function) in a bit more detail? I get lost pretty quickly as soon as the .map() method introduced.

Comment: @AaronSawatsky: Two things.  First that `const handler = (() => {...})()` block covers everything but the last two lines.  It is just a way (using closures) to keep our local variables out of the global scope, exposing only `start` and `stop`.  You can look up `IIFE` to find out more.  Second, the first block inside that IIFE simply defines `red`, `blue`, etc. as objects that have a `play` method on them.  The details are not relevant to your underlying question.  If I find time (unlikely, I'm afraid) I will update with more details.  You can focus on `start`, `stop`, `running` and `interval`.

Comment: No sweat about no having the time to expand. I appreciate all your help and time nonetheless! I'll be sure to look into IIFE some more.